# Cannot import z3 in python-2.7.12 in ubuntu even after installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, z3, z3py

I tried installing z3 theorem prover.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
And I am using Python 2.7.12

I did the installation in two ways:

1. I used `sudo apt-get install z3`

   But when I tried to import z3 by opening **python** from **terminal** using `from z3 import *` and also using `import z3 as z` I got an error saying `No Module named z3`
2. I used

   `python scripts/mk_make.py
   cd build
   make
   sudo make install`

and also added `build/python` to `PYTHONPATH` and `build` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but I got the same problem when i tried to import z3 using the same way.

Now I tried running `examples.py`
which is the folder `build/python`

And lo!!! No Error!!!

I also tried running other example files and I didn't get any error for them too.

Can anybody help me with the problem why I cannot import z3 when I open Python from terminal or any other folder outside of `build/python`?

EDIT:

I found out that I have to do adding the folders to the path every time I open a terminal outside of `build/python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I have to add the paths everytime I open a new terminal window. Then only z3 can be imported from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Python module install by `pip`. you can try with:

```
pip install z3
```

Comment: using pip shows

 `Collecting z3

  Using cached z3-0.1.15.tar.gz`

But I need z3-4.4.0 or higher :(

Comment: 0.1.15 is the [latest version](https://github.com/presslabs/z3) of the pypi package at the time of writing.  The 4.4.x package is a [different thing entirely called "z3"](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) -- which one do you want?

Comment: I want the "different thing entirely called z3", i.e. the z3 theorem prover

Comment: I can't import z3 from outside the folder "z3-master/build/python" or "z3/bin/python"
But if I paste the files I want to run in that folder then it works fine. I want to be able to import z3 from any folder I want.

Comment: Note that `pip install z3-solver` is different than `pip install z3` at this time. As mentioned above, make sure to pick the correct package.